# Angular 2/4 @Input only moves intrinsics - not lists or objects

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

I am trying to @Input a list of objects; this results in the @Input variable being undefined.

What works:
home.component.html:

```html
<p>
  <it-easy [mycount]="countItem" (result)="PrintResult($event)"></it-easy>
  home works for {{countItem}}!
</p>
<p>
  calculation result is: {{calcResult}}
</p>
```

And the code in home.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'it-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  countItem: number;
  calcResult: number;

  constructor() {
    this.countItem = 5;
    this.calcResult = 0;

  }
  PrintResult($event) {
    this.calcResult = +$event;
  }
}
```

It-Easy gets the inputs (and outputs) like this:

```js
export class EasyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('mycount') count = 0;
  @Output('result') calculation = new EventEmitter<number>();
  constructor() {
    alert('count is ' + this.count);
  }
```

So I made some adjustments to try sending a list of objects shown here from the same Home.component.html.

```js
myNodesList: {title: string, count: number}[];
this.myNodesList = [
  {title: "first", count: 1},
  {title: "second", count: 2},
  {title: "third", count: 3},
];
```

Home.html now looks like:

```html
<p>
  <it-hard [node]="myNodesList"></it-hard>
</p>
```

Now the part that FAILS:  it-hard.component.ts

```js
})
export class HardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() node: {title: string, count: number}[];
  constructor() {
    const length = this.node.length;
  }
```

And node is "undefined" .. in fact blows in the constructor at node.length.

Any thoughts?  (without a fix, I'm going to have to run things through a service).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Dont access `@Input` parameters in construcor. Use `ngOnInit` if you don't use `async` pipe and use `ngOnChanges` if you do use `async` pipe.

---

You are trying to access `@Input` properties too early in Angulars component Lifecycle. `Constructor` is not the lifecycle hook itself and its not a place to access `@Input` parameters.

Generally about hooks:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

As that page say:

> The constructor isn't an Angular hook per se. The log confirms that input properties (the name property in this case) have no assigned values at construction.

You should wait at least for `ngOnInit()` and access it there although there are more considerations about it here:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#when-to-set-form-model-values-ngonchanges

Namely, even in `ngOnChanges`, although it fires first time before `ngOnInit`, when using `aysnc` pipe you still might not have data in `ngOnInit`. So, as a safest and standard way, you should access your `@Input` in `ngOnChanges` and inspect its parameters to filter those `@Input` parameters that are of your interest at the moment.

Comment: Excellent.  I believe without a doubt you are right.  This gives me everything I need to move forward.  Thanks very much.  (upticking)